# How to map HashMap components in React?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, hashmap

I have an item called workspace, which has a HashMap called permissionsMap:

private HashMap<String, String> permissionsMap

I'm trying to design a form in React using material UI where the user can select the workspace and update his permissions.

I have tried, this way but I don't get how to map it correctly:
const [ workspace, setWorkspace ] = useState({
name: "",
permissionsMap : [],
});

```
<Grid item xs={12}>
  <TextField
    id="permissions"
    name="permissions"
    value={workspace.permissionsMap}      //should it be .map()?
    fullWidth
  />
</Grid>
```

I also tried mapping it with key/value but it does not work:

```
<TableContainer component={Paper}>
    <Table>
        <TableBody>
           {workspace.permissionsMap.map((key,value) => (
             <TableRow key={key}>
             <TableCell>{value}</TableCell>
             </TableRow>
           ))}
        </TableBody>
    </Table>
</TableContainer>
```

does someone know how to handle with this HashMaps in React?

Thanks in advance

Comment: what is the value are you getting in permissionsMap array?

Comment: I can't see the page because is not loading the table properly.

Comment: If I print workspace.permissionsMap I'm getting [object Object] so it seems like is someway parsing the String into Object